# Openacc error ibgomp: while loading libgomp-plugin-host_nonshm.so.1: libgomp-plugin-host_nonshm.so.1: cannot

Tags: openacc, libgomp

I want to compile an easy openacc sample (it was attached) , it was correctly compiled but when i run it got an error :

1. compile with : gcc-5 -fopenacc accVetAdd.c -lm
2. run with : ./a.out
3. got error in runtime

> **error:** libgomp: while loading libgomp-plugin-host_nonshm.so.1: libgomp-plugin-host_nonshm.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I google it and find only one page! then i ask how to fix this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Size of vectors
    int n = 10000;

    // Input vectors
    double *restrict a;
    double *restrict b;
    // Output vector
    double *restrict c;

    // Size, in bytes, of each vector
    size_t bytes = n*sizeof(double);

    // Allocate memory for each vector
    a = (double*)malloc(bytes);
    b = (double*)malloc(bytes);
    c = (double*)malloc(bytes);

    // Initialize content of input vectors, vector a[i] = sin(i)^2 vector b[i] = cos(i)^2
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        a[i] = sin(i)*sin(i);
        b[i] = cos(i)*cos(i);
    }

    // sum component wise and save result into vector c
    #pragma acc kernels copyin(a[0:n],b[0:n]), copyout(c[0:n])
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
    // Sum up vector c and print result divided by n, this should equal 1 within error
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        sum += c[i];
    }
    sum = sum / n;
    printf("final result: %f\n", sum);

    // Release memory
    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

libgomp dynamically loads shared object files for the plugins it supports, such as the one implementing the *host_nonshm* device.  If they're installed in a non-standard directory (that is, not in the system's default search path), you need to tell the dynamic linker where to look for these shared object files: either compile with `-Wl,-rpath,[...]`, or set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.